# error TF400013: An unexpected database error occurred. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator. (Code: 207)

Tags: tfs

I have a project in *Visual Studio Team foundation server 2013*. Under test tab, test plan i have created the test cases in the project. I have received the error

> "TF400013: An unexpected database error occurred. Contact your Team
>   Foundation Server administrator. (Code: 207)"

and now i am unable to access my test cases. i am able to access few other test case.

It is related to *TFS 2013*.

Error msg:

> TF400013: An unexpected database error occurred. Contact your Team
>   Foundation Server administrator. (Code: 207)

Comment: Since you're asking us, and not your Team Foundation Server administrator, I guess you are effectively the administrator? Do you have any logs or event logs from the service, or the database, that give you any more detail? There are [some steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50957913/243245) that you can follow to see the failing query, if you have tried those already.

Comment: There are multiple reasons for this kind of issue. Please also check if there are some more useful information in Event View. Besides, also take a look at this 
 similar error and solution in  TFS2013 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916425/tfs-2012-tf400013-an-unexpected-database-error-occurred  Check if its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that it may be bug in your version of TFS:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/980cd923-801f-4d1b-a1a2-21c802b74053/bug-in-team-web-test-plan-view-tfs-2013-update-5?forum=tfsworkitemtracking